# C++ UTF-8 support on Unix / Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, unix, encoding, utf-8

I need a way to be able to read from a UTF-8 encoded file and store data from it into "UTF-8 compatible strings" of some sort, in C++. This data needs to be written back to a UTF-8 encoded file later on. There seems to be a lot of advice on google about doing this in Windows but I cannot find any help for Unix systems.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is read and write it then std::string is fine.

```
std::ifstream    fileIn("file.utf8");

std::string   line;
std::getline(fileIn, line); // Reads a UTF-8 line

std::ofstream    fileOut("OutFile.utf8");
fileOut << line; // Writes a line of UTF-8 text
```

This works because no multi-character UTF codepoint overlaps with an an ASCII character so the standard processing of text works just fine in relation to end of line sequence and there is no other processing done by the stream. What you read is what you get. Outputting the string does not change any of the codepoints.

Now if you need to manipulate the text that is a different question and gets more complex.

Usually manipulating UTF-8 is way to hard (can be done but not worth it IMO).

When it comes to manipulating the text you want to convert the UTF-8 (which is not a fixed width) to an internal fixed width format; (UTF-16 or UTF-32 are common formats for manipulation and easy to use; (UTF-16 windows, UTF-32 for most *nix like OS)). The easiest way to do this is to imbue the stream with a facet that knows the input is in UTF-8 and will convert it automatically.

There are a couple of these facets floating around in different libraries. But an easy one to find is boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html

Note: It is also in the latest version of [boost 1.46](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp)

```
std::locale old_locale;
std::locale utf8_locale(old_locale,new utf8_codecvt_facet<ucs4_t>);
                              //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  The important bit
                              //   Note here we are converting to UTF-32(UCS-4)

std::wifstream fileIn;
fileIn.imbue(utf8_locale);    // Imbue the stream with the knowledge.

fileIn.open("file.utf8");
// Now read wide characters from the stream. The UTF-8 file is converted 
// into UTF-16/UTF-32 for internal processing.

std::wstring    wideLine;
std::getline(fileIn, wideLine); // Read a line converting to UTF-16/32
```

The processes is the same for writting UTF-16/32 back to a stream and converting it to UTF-8

```
std::wofstream fileOut;
fileOut.imbue(utf8_locale);

fileOut.open("OutFile.utf8");
fileOut << wideLine;      // Write a UTF-16/32 line and convert into UTF-8
```

Note. You should imbue the file before it is opened. Different implementations of the stream will react differently if you imbue the stream after it is open. Thus it is best to imbue the stream before opening it.

Dinkumware also has a set of conversion facets (not sure if they are free).
http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/default.aspx?manual=compleat&page=index_cvt.html#Code%20Conversions

Note: I prefer to use the terms UTF-X rather than UCS-Y. Though technically there are very minor differences these are inconsequential compared to the confusion you can create by switching between the two terms while talking about the subject. Stick to one unless you need to talk explicitly about a feature (like Surrogate pairs).

Comment: But UTF-16 isn't any easier to (correctly) process than UTF-8.  Both require you to deal with multi-element codepoints.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes I agree that to do it properly for UTF-16 is hard because you need to deal with surrogate pairs and thus personally I prefer UTF-32 (BUT usually your platform leaves you little choice). BUT: UTF-16 is a lot easier than UTF-8 as surrogate pairs only deal with codepoints that are not on the BMP (>16 bitis), which for most application is sufficient (though short sighted). As long as you protect surrogate pairs from tampering a lot of the time a simple warning that they can not be displayed correctly can be sufficient (unless you are dealing with sandscript etc).

Comment: Note: Though UTF-32 is 32 bits. They have agreed not to use more than 15 supplementary plains so technically you can get all characters into 20 bits. Though I bet on first alien contact we will need a couple of more plains. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_plane) for what has currently been assigned to the supplementary plains (very little of use to normal applications (with apologies to the Chinese as some `extensions` to CJK are here)).